# How to add save data in local on Data Grid DevExtreme by keyboard Enter?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, devextreme

[image]

I want when creating row for the first time. Enter data and when you press Enter it will save the data local on the data grid. Then create new row

[image]

I handle the event enter event. But then it didn't save my previously entered data.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a timing problem. The text editor inside the data grid cell does not save the input to the data source if the `saveEditData` method is called inside the `onKeyDown` event. The method `addRow()` should be called after text editor saved the input to the data source.

I would prefer using the [`onSaved`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onSaved) event to add a new row after using the enter key.

Example:

```js
class MyComponent {

    requestNewRow = false;

    handleOnEnterKey(e) {
        if (e.event.originalEvent.key === 'Enter') {
            this.requestNewRow = true;
        }
    }

    handleOnSaved(e) {
        if (this.requestNewRow) {
            this.requestNewRow = false;
            e.component.addRow();
        }
    }
}
```